# Restructuring Javascript Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a set of data which I'm trying to convert it into a different structure. I have almost reached the requirement but I'm stuck at the last part. Here's the code and what I have tried so far.

```js
let array1 = [
  {
    aggr_type: "mean",
    date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
    mean: [13.87, 8.42],
    name: "TEMPERATURE",
    sum: [0.1, 0.2]
  },
  {
    aggr_type: "sum",
    date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
    mean: [45.42, 55.22],
    name: "HUMIDITY",
    sum: [0.3, 0.5]
  }
];
let names = [];
array1.forEach(el => {
  names.push(el.name);
});
const myObj = names.reduce((a, key) => Object.assign(a, { [key]: null, date: null }), {});
// console.log(myObj);
// console.log(array1);
let arrays = []

for(i=0; i < array1[0].date.length; i++) {
  array1.forEach(el => {
    myObj.date = el.date[i];
    myObj[el.name] = el.[el.aggr_type][i];
    arrays.push(myObj);
  });
}

console.log(arrays);
```

If this snippet isn't working use this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/KKZJOXd?editors=0012)

I'm supposed to have the output like this.

```
    [
{
  'TEMPERATURE': '13.87',
 'date': '19 Apr',
 'HUMIDITY': '0.3'
},
{
  'TEMPERATURE': '8.42', 
  'date': '20 Apr', 
  'HUMIDITY': '0.5'
}
];
```

But it only returns the last index. Is there any way to get the output like I've mentioned above.

NOTE: The values should be added the final output based on the `aggr_type`

Comment: What is up with `aggr_type`?

Comment: @AdamOrłowski sorry I have updated my question.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. It is confusing.

Comment: If  you go through my code you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snipppet**

```js
// method to obtain the desired objective
const groupByDate = arr => (
  Object.values(        // extract only the "values" from result of "reduce"
    arr.reduce(         // use "reduce" to iterate over the array
      (acc, {name, date, mean}) => {
        date.forEach(   // for each "date" in the "date-array"
          (d, i) => {   // populate / update the "acc" (accumulator)
            acc[d] = {
              ...(acc[d] || {}),
              [name]: mean[i],    // this line populates either temperator or humidity
              date: d,
            }
          }
        )
        return acc;       // always return the "acc" 
      },
      {}                  // initially the "acc" is set as an empty object
    )
  )
);

let array1 = [
  {
    aggr_type: "mean",
    date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
    mean: [13.87, 8.42],
    name: "TEMPERATURE",
    sum: [0.1, 0.2]
  },
  {
    aggr_type: "sum",
    date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
    mean: [45.42, 55.22],
    name: "HUMIDITY",
    sum: [0.3, 0.5]
  }
];

console.log(groupByDate(array1));
```

**Explanation**
Inline comments in the above snippet explain the significant aspects.

**EDIT**

Used the input array `array1` that was updated on the question. The answer from the snippet matches with the expected array on the question:

```
[
{
  'TEMPERATURE': '13.87',
 'date': '19 Apr',
 'HUMIDITY': '45.42'
},
{
  'TEMPERATURE': '8.42', 
  'date': '20 Apr', 
  'HUMIDITY': '55.22'
}
];
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```js
// method to obtain the desired objective
const groupByDate = arr => (
  Object.values(        // extract only the "values" from result of "reduce"
    arr.reduce(         // use "reduce" to iterate over the array
      (acc, ob) => {
        const {name, date, aggr_type} = ob;
        const tgt = ob[aggr_type];    // decide whether to use "mean" or "sum"
        date.forEach(   // for each "date" in the "date-array"
          (d, i) => {   // populate / update the "acc" (accumulator)
            acc[d] = {
              ...(acc[d] || {}),
              [name]: tgt[i],    // this line populates either temperature or humidity
              date: d,
            }
          }
        )
        return acc;       // always return the "acc" 
      },
      {}                  // initially the "acc" is set as an empty object
    )
  )
);

let array1 = [
  {
    aggr_type: "mean",
    date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
    mean: [13.87, 8.42],
    name: "TEMPERATURE",
    sum: [0.1, 0.2]
  },
  {
    aggr_type: "sum",
    date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
    mean: [45.42, 55.22],
    name: "HUMIDITY",
    sum: [0.3, 0.5]
  }
];

console.log(groupByDate(array1));
```

Comment: I have updated my question, because the key `mean` could be random.

Comment: can you add the numbers based on `aggr_func` of the value instead of putting just `mean`

Comment: There is nothing named `aggr_func` in the question - I assume `aggr_type`. **EDIT 2** achieves the new output mentioned in the question. Thank you ! (Nandri vanakkam !)

Comment: Nandrigal thala  :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have created a single `myObj`

```js
const myObj = names.reduce((a, key) =>
                  Object.assign(a, { [key]: null, date: null }), {});
```

and you assign to it and then push it within your loop

```js
for (i=0; i < array1[0].date.length; i++) {
    array1.forEach(el => {
                       myObj.date = el.date[i];  // <-- modifies the ONE 'myObj'
                       myObj[el.name] = el.[el.aggr_type][i];
                       arrays.push(myObj); // <-- pushes the ONE myObj (again)
    });
}
```

You end up with 4 references to `myObj` in your `arrays` — each time you assign to it, for example `myObj.date = el.date[i]`, you are modifying that *one and only* `myObj` ... That is, after the first time you do `arrays.push(myObj)` you have `arrays[0]` containing `myObj`, then the next time through the loop when you assign values to myObj again that is changing the values that are in `arrays[0]` since that ***is*** `myObj`.

You can treat `myObj` as a *prototype* — you need separate instances of objects that look like `myObj` so each one pushed into `arrays` is a unique object.

Modifying your original code as little as possible, here is *one way* that could be done:

```js
let array1 = [
    {
        aggr_type: "mean",
        date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
        mean: [13.87, 8.42],
        name: "TEMPERATURE",
    },
    {
        aggr_type: "mean1",
        date: ['19 Apr', '20 Apr'],
        mean: [45.42, 55.22],
        name: "HUMIDITY",
    }
];
let names = [];
array1.forEach(el => {
    names.push(el.name);
});
// Changed the name here so I wouldn't have to change it in the loop
const protoMyObj = names.reduce((a, key) =>
    Object.assign(a, { [key]: null, date: null }), {});
// console.log(myObj);
// console.log(array1);
let arrays = []

for (i=0; i < array1[0].date.length; i++) {
    array1.forEach(el => {
        // Make a new copy of the "prototype" `protoMyObj`
        let myObj = Object.assign({}, protoMyObj);
        myObj.date = el.date[i];
        myObj[el.name] = el.mean[i];
        arrays.push(myObj);
    });
}

console.log(arrays);
```